# How do we approach a counting exercise from Enumerative Combinatorics (Prof. Stanley's book)?

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory

I am baffled by the first question in the exercise of Chapter 3, Enumerative Combinatorics. I have no idea how to approach it. The question reads:

> [3] What is the connection between a partially ordered set and itinerant salespersons
>   who take revenge on customers who don’t pay their bills?

Can somebody give me a reference?

Thanks!

Comment: I can find no trace of such a question; is this a new edition? Anyway, the book has a section solutions to exercises.

Comment: It sounds more like a joke. Like, what do you get when you take the lexicographic product of a monkey and an elephant?

Comment: Dear Asaf, What is the answer to that question?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: So what do you get when you take the lexicographic product of a monkey and an elephant? (except a headache)

Comment: @Marc: Some failed experiment in math jokes. Ordered lexicographically. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Asaf suspects, it's a joke, and as Marc points out, there are solutions in the book. The edition I found on Google books has this on page 408:

Itinerant salespersons who take revenge on customers 
who don't pay their bills are retaliatory peddlers, and “retaliatory peddlers” is an 
anagram of “partially ordered set” (i.e., they have the same multiset of letters).

Comment: Hello Gerry,
I knew it was a joke. But I was not getting the joke. I thought it was some clever pun on transitivity or covering relations. I would have never guessed that answer. No wonder, it was rated [3]. 

Anyway, I didn't know EC had solutions. Thanks for that.